# How to use OR in Parse.com Query of Objective-C library

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I want to run following query in Parse.com Objective-C library for iOS and wondering how to do it.

```
Select * From Table Where firstName = "" OR lastName = "";
```

How I can achieve this in Objective-C library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do by using orQueryWithSubqueries as :

```
PFQuery *Query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"yourClassName"];
[Query1 whereKey:@"firstName" equalTo:@""];

PFQuery *Query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"yourClassName"];
[sQuery2 whereKey:@"lastName" equalTo:@""];

NSArray *arrQuery = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:Query1,Query2, nil];
PFQuery *mainQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:arrQuery];

[mainQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *arrRes,NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"All data is = %@",arrRes);
    } else {
        DisplayAlertWithTitle(@"Error",@"Unable to get record");
    }
}];
```

I think this will work for you.let me know if you any other question on parse.